# Using `Object.defineProperty` with RangeError

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use `Object.defineProperty` to update my `obj` object to have a `get` and `set` accessor on `obj.name`.

```
var obj = {};

Object.defineProperty(obj, 'name', { 
    get: function() { return this.name; },
    set: function(x) { this.name = x; }
});

console.log("obj:", obj);
console.log("obj.name:", obj.name);
```

But I'm getting a `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`.

How can I use `Object.defineProperty` to add `get` and `set` accessors on the `name` property in `obj`?

http://jsfiddle.net/kman007_us/ZwYp6/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you get `obj.name`, the `get` function is called, which returns the value of `this.name`.
When you get `this.name`, the `get` function is called, which returns the value of `this.name`.
When you get `this.name`, the `get` function is called, which returns the value of `this.name`.
When you get `this.name`, the `get` function is called, which returns the value of `this.name`.
When you get `this.name`, the `get` function is called, which returns the value of `this.name`.
When you get `this.name`, the `get` function is called, which returns the value of `this.name`.
When you get `this.name`, the `get` function is called, which returns the value of `this.name`.
When you get `this.name`, the `get` function is called, which returns the value of `this.name`.
When you get `this.name`, the `get` function is called, which returns the value of `this.name`.
When you get `this.name`, the `get` function is called, which returns the value of `this.name`.
When you get `this.name`, the `get` function is called, which returns the value of `this.name`.
When you get `this.name`, the `get` function is called, which returns the value of `this.name`.
When you get `this.name`, the `get` function is called, which returns the value of `this.name`.
When you get `this.name`, the `get` function is called, which returns the value of `this.name`.
When you get `this.name`, the `get` function is called, which returns the value of `this.name`.
When you get `this.name`, the `get` function is called, which returns the value of `this.name`.
When you get `this.name`, the `get` function is called, which returns the value of `this.name`.
When you get `this.name`, the `get` function is called, which returns the value of `this.name`.
When you get `this.name`, the `get` function is called, which returns the value of `this.name`.
When you get `this.name`, the `get` function is called, which returns the value of `this.name`.
When you get `this.name`, the `get` function is called, which returns the value of `this.name`.
When you get `this.name`, the `get` function is called, which returns the value of `this.name`.
When you get `this.name`, the `get` function is called, which returns the value of `this.name`.
When you get `this.name`, the `get` function is called, which returns the value of `this.name`.
When you get `this.name`, the `get` function is called, which returns the value of `this.name`.
When you get `this.name`, the `get` function is called, which returns the value of `this.name`.
When you get `this.name`, the `get` function is called, which returns the value of `this.name`.
When you get `this.name`, the `get` function is called, which returns the value of `this.name`.
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.

---

Try `return this.__name;` and `this.__name = x;` instead.

Comment: could you please explain what `this.__name` is?

Comment: @KevinMeredith: Just a different property that does not recursively invoke the getter.

Comment: It's just an alternative variable name. By convention, names starting with `__` are for internal use (which is what you're using it for here).

Comment: would either of you please fix my fiddle to show an example? I'm not sure how to call `get` or `set`.

Comment: @KevinMeredith You don't call them. They are called internally when you get and set the property.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot access a property in the getters or setters by the same name as a property you are defining using `Object.defineProperty`. You've created a recursive function call that never exits.