# JavaScript classes with getter and setter cause RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-mysql

I am currently experimenting with ECMA6 classes.
My current class looks like the following

```
class Player {
  constructor(id) {
    this.id = id;
    this.cash = 350;
  }

  get cash() {
    return this.cash;
  }

  set cash(value) { // line 19
    this.cash = value; // line 20
  }
};
```

When I am now creating a new Object by calling `let playerObject = new Player(1);` I receive the following error

```
...\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:82
        throw err;
              ^
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at Player.cash (player.js:19:11)
    at Player.cash (player.js:20:15)
    at Player.cash (player.js:20:15)
    at Player.cash (player.js:20:15)
    at Player.cash (player.js:20:15)
    at Player.cash (player.js:20:15)
    at Player.cash (player.js:20:15)
    at Player.cash (player.js:20:15)
    at Player.cash (player.js:20:15)
    at Player.cash (player.js:20:15)
Press enter to exit
```

What does this have to do with the mysql library? Why does the error is multiple times in the same line? I am only calling it once.

Comment: I don't know enough about ECMA6 classes, but it seems like you are calling your setter recursively.

Comment: What does calling recursively mean?

Comment: It means that it is calling itself. Try renaming your setter method to something other than cash.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using \`Object.defineProperty\` with RangeError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23938419/using-object-defineproperty-with-rangeerror)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Your "cash" setter calls the "cash" setter, which calls the "cash" setter, which calls the "cash" setter...

Accessing the property setter by its own name inside the setter creates an infinite recursive function call.

Comment: Renaming the "internal" variable. I changed `this.cash` to `this.playerCash`. Thanks Y'all.

Comment: @Cludch Not a problem. You should get in the habit of not reusing names for things, or if you really want to use that name add something like "get" or "set" in front, i.e "getCash" or "setCash".

Answer (score 18):

I know I'm late, but I think I can clarify one or two points here:

First, there is the question of **privacy**, which is a long term discussion in the JavaScript community.

```
class Player {
   constructor(id) {
      this.cash = 350; // this._cash, alternatively
   }

   get cash() {
      return this.cash;
   }

   set cash(value) {
      this.cash = value;
   }
};

let player1 = new Player();
```

In this case, **this.cash is a public property**, so you don't really need a getter and a setter method to handle it, because you can get it with **player1.cash** and set it with **player1.cash = newCash**; and it is throwing the error because the getter and the setter are being called recursively, as mentioned by others.

However, if you simply rename the property to **this._cash**, you have to understand that this **IS NOT A PRIVATE PROPERTY**. If you try to access **player1._cash**, you will have access to the property value in the same way you will have with **player1.cash**.

So, **how do we get privacy poperly implemented?**

There are 2 main ways of doing this with ES6/ES2015: Using the new primitive type **[Symbol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol)** or using **[WeakMaps](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap)**. I'm not going into details about this two new features of the language, but I'll show how this would be implemented in this case.

### Using Symbols:

```
const CASH = Symbol();

class Player {

   constructor () {
      this[CASH] = 350;
   }

   get cash(){
      return this[CASH];
   }

   set cash(cash) {
      this[CASH] = cash;
   }

}
```

### Using WeakMaps

```
let map =  new WeakMap();

class Player {

   constructor () {
      map.set(this, {
         cash: 350
      });    
   }

   get cash(){
      return map.get(this).cash;
   }

   set cash(cash) {
      map.get(this).cash = cash;
   }

}
```

## IMPORTANT

While the syntax for Symbols are better, it requires native support of the browser to actually work. You can write it with a transpiler but, under the hood, it will mock it to old ES5 standards. The native support for WeakMaps are better and, on the other hand, this feature just plays with the GC and with the enumerable option of the objects properties. So, in the end, it's your choice.

Comment: Really annoying. If I do this, what happens when I want to serialize/deserialize the object? I believe it would be serialized as `"{'_cash': 350}"` which isn't ideal for sending over the wire. You will have to write a custom `toString()` function to deal with this.

Answer (score 5):

cash represents the getter/setter, _cash is the 'private' property.

```
  set cash(value) { // line 19
      this._cash = value; // line 20
  }
```

Have a look at [this page](http://es6-features.org/#GetterSetter) for a clear example.

Answer (score 4):

You are calling recursively your getter.

It follows a possible alternative:

```
class Player {
    constructor(id) {
        this.id = id;
        this._cash = 350;
    }

    get cash() {
        return this._cash;
    }

    set cash(value) {
        this._cash = value;
    }
};
```

Another one using `Object.defineProperty`:

```
class Player {
    constructor(id) {
        this.id = id;

        var _cash = 350;
        Object.defineProperty(this, 'cash', {
            get: function() {
                return _cash;
            }

            set: function(v) {
                _cash = v;
            }
        });
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

> Get & Set ES6 classes brings a new syntax for getters and setters on
>   object properties. Get and set allows us to run code on the reading or
>   writing of a property. ES5 had getters and setters as well but was not
>   widely used because of older IE browsers. ES5 getters and setters did
>   not have as nice of a syntax that ES6 brings us. So lets create a get
>   and set for our name property.
>
> Source: [JavaScript ES6 Class Syntax](http://coryrylan.com/blog/javascript-es6-class-syntax)

**Example**:

```
// ES6 get and set
class Person {
    constructor(name) {
        this._name = name;
    }

    get name() {
        return this._name.toUpperCase();
    }

    set name(newName) {
        this._name = newName;   // validation could be checked here such as only allowing non numerical values
    }

    walk() {
        console.log(this._name + ' is walking.');
    }
}

let bob = new Person('Bob');
console.log(bob.name);  // Outputs 'BOB'
```